# can not make svg image half page

Tags: html

i have this svg image code (since its too long i wont type in script)  the problem is i can't make this svg as half cover page, any help?

```html
    <div class="container" style="width: 200%;">
        <div class="row">
            <svg width="794" height="571" viewBox="0 0 794 571" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect width="794" height="571" fill="#F6EAFF"/>

                </svg>
                
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nested your svg, with a div and put a class on it.
With this class you can adjust height and width

Very simple example :

```css
.container-svg{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 200%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-svg" >
            <svg width="100%" height="571" viewBox="0 0 794 571" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect width="794" height="571" fill="#F6EAFF"/>

                </svg>
            </div
                
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make the SVG's container 50% of the height of your screen:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="row">
        <svg
          width="auto"
          height="50vh"
          viewBox="0 0 794 571"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <rect width="794" height="571" fill="#F6EAFF" />
        </svg>
      </div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <svg width="100%" height="100vh">
      <rect width="100%" height="50vh" style="fill: rgb(226, 127, 33)" />
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please better explain what you want to achieve? That worked for me, but maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: i'm creating static website, starting with home page, i wanted to have half page full width background svg image